# Nesting react components dynamically , adding custom JSX on the fly inside the component?

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="header">
   <Card>
      <div className="logo">
          <Logo />
      </div>
      <div className="timer">
          <Timer />
      </div>
   </Card>
</div>
```

I want to achieve something like this . I have created a component Card , Now I want that this component should contain any random JSX as well as other components .

I have got the way of nesting React Children using React.Children method , But I am not able to find , how to handle the additional JSX inside the component .

Comment: It's just `{this.props.children}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [this.props.children](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html).

To handle this specific data-structure, you can use the [React.Children utilities](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children).

For example, if in your case you just want to add a wrapping div for every child component in Card, you can write:

```
const Card = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        const wrappedChildren = React.Children.map(
            this.props.children,
            function(oneChild) {
                return (
                    <div className="wrappingDiv">
                        {oneChild}
                    </div>
                );
            },
        );
        return (
            <div className="cardContainer">
                {wrappedChildren}
            </div>
        );
    },
});

// then:
<Card>
   <Logo />
   <Timer />
</Card>
```

Comment: The wrapping div may contain different classes based on some condition and I want to segregate the logic from the Card Component .

Comment: Then you can forget the wrappedChildren thing in Card component and simply replace it by this.props.children inside the container-div. You can render your components as you wrote them in your question. Do you still have a problem then?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your problem. Could you please explain it with proper code example by editing your question?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        var el = (<component_you_want_to_nest />);
        return(
            <ComponentCardComponent nestComp={el} />
        )
    }
});

var ComponentCardComponent = React.createClass({
render : function(){
    <div>
        {this.props.nestComp}
    </div>
}
```

});

Comment: I think you can do `children={el}` and `this.props.children`